# Java LDAP returning always a single value instead of a list

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I want to query my ldap to give me **all** users where `sn` contains a specific value (`maier`). However I always get a single result.

```
public LdapContext getLdapContext(){
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try{
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.url:389");
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");
    }catch(NamingException nex){
        System.out.println("LDAP Connection: FAILED");
        nex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}

private User getUserBasicAttributes(String username, LdapContext ctx) {
    User user=null;
    try {

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attrIDs = { "distinguishedName",
                "sn",
                "givenname",
                "mail",
                "telephonenumber"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        constraints.setCountLimit(200);
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=myDc,DC=com", "sn=*maier*", constraints);
        if (answer.hasMore()) {
            Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            System.out.println("distinguishedName "+ attrs.get("distinguishedName"));
            System.out.println("givenname "+ attrs.get("givenname"));
            System.out.println("sn "+ attrs.get("sn"));
            System.out.println("mail "+ attrs.get("mail"));
            System.out.println("telephonenumber "+ attrs.get("telephonenumber"));
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: How do you *expect* your code to ever print more than one result? (Hint: you'd need a loop. You don't have a loop...)

Comment: hm.. I do have `if (answer.hasMore()) {` and answer.next. This should work, shoudn't it ?

Comment: No. Is an `if` statement a loop? How many times do you think you're calling `answer.hasMore()`? Think about it carefully.

Comment: oh my god. Sorry for the stupid question and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looping, so of course you're only getting one result. Change `if (answer.hasMore())` to `while (answer.hasMore())`.

Comment: @Akarienta Rubbish. It *is* the answer. Reiterated in the comments below the answer, and acknowledged by the OP.

Comment: @Akarienta I take it that any competent programmer should immediately understand the point of changing `if` to `while`. Adopting this solution solves the problem and therefore answers the question. It is asinine to continue pretending otherwise.

Comment: @Akarienta  I don't know what that means. If you're not a competent reviewer, don't review. As the OP has now accepted this answer your comments are now looking quite ridiculous.

Comment: Yes, taking back then. Sorry.